# Notation for state space

Tags: notation, markov-chains

I am trying to describe a state space of a process in mathematical notation.

The process begins with L individuals, $X(i)$, all of a unique starting type $X_0(i)$. At each time step, a new generation of L individuals are generated, randomly choosing one of the previous generation's types. Over time types go extinct, eventually leaving just one type.

The state space can be described as each of the L individuals being able to have one of the L unique starting types. So the size of this state space is LxL.

I'm struggling to write this in mathematical notation. So far I have

$X(i) \in X_0(j) \ \text{ where } \ i,j \in \{1,2,...,L\}$

Or it could be something like:

$X(i) \in \{ X_0(j) : j \in \{1,2,..,L\}\} \forall  i \in \{1,2,...,L\}$

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Try (L^L)^N ... For each time t in N, you have a function from L to L that describes the type (points in that set are functions from N to (functions from L to types)). The points of LxL does not describe L individuals have one of L types. It describes a pair of individual, type. Btw - it will be more clear if you have another set name for the types, e.g. T.

Comment: @Lorenzo yeah thanks, I'll defo take on your tip of having a seperate set name for the types - great idea

Comment: By identifying equivalent states, we can define the set space as the set of [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of $L$.